# Samsung S6 screen is out. Can I recover my files?

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, file-transfer, broken-screen, android-pc

My issue is pretty much what the title says. I dropped my Samsung Galaxy S6 yesterday, contacted my insurance company, and will be receiving a new phone tomorrow. I work in the vet med field and have a ton of patient pictures on my phone that are needed for consultations with clients and varying specialists (not to mention my personal memories). My screen is in the process of being taken over by a black and purple blob and is completely out of order. I can still make calls via my Jeep's BT connection since I never disconnected. Is there any way to salvage my files and upload them to my PC? When I attempt to open my cell phone's folder after connecting to the PC, the folder is emtpy. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance for any helpful advice or straight truth in the "I'm SOL" department.

Comment: The empty folder is there because the device is locked. Are you able to unlock the device somehow (fingerprint)?

Comment: Fingerprint stopped working a while ago when my phone was ran over (miraculously it survived). I have no idea how to unlock it. My screen doesn't react at all to touching.

Comment: Please take a look into the data-recovery section of our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info), which has some approaches.

Comment: Anytime! Let us know when your issue is solved – and if one of the questions linked from the wiki is a direct hit, espacially that :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier the empty folder is there because your device is locked.

Try unlocking your device by using Samsung's Find my Mobile Service - https://findmymobile.samsung.com/

If you did not create a Samsung account or do not remember creating one then try signing in with your Gmail ID and password.